# Artemis REST API (through Jolokia) for clearing all messages on all queues

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there any API that can help me clear messages in all queues withing Artemis?

```
mbean: "org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"1.1.1.1\",component=addresses,address=\"myaddressName\",subcomponent=queues,routing-type=\"multicast\",queue=\"myqueueName\""
operation: "removeAllMessages()"
type: "exec"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no programmatic way to simply delete all the data from every queue on the broker. However, you can combine a few management operations (e.g. in a script) to get the same result. You can use the [`getQueueNames`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#getQueueNames--) method to get the name of every queue and then pass those names to the [`destroyQueue(String)`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#destroyQueue-java.lang.String-) method.

However, the simplest way to clear all the data would probably be to simply stop the broker, clear the data directory, and then restart the broker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually go with manually list all queues and then removeMessage on each one then. As for stopping broker and clear data directory, it's not an option in my case.